# How do I give another person admin rights to a company profile so they can edit it on LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin, profile

Someone else at my company created a LinkedIn company profile for our business. Both of us will be doing a lot of editing for it though.

It would be nice if we both had the ability to edit the blog and whatnot for the company profile. I'm assuming this would be done though some admin rights section.

Answer (score 3):

This can absolutely be done. It's very simple.

Go to your company page. Click Admin Tools >> Edit Page. One of the first option is "Company Pages Admins". Here you can either select that ANY employee with the company domain in their email can edit the page OR you can select specific users (type in their name to add them to the admin panel). Publish your changes and you're golden!

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure the other person meets the requirements for editing a Company Profile:
   https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1594/
2. Make sure the other person has correctly associated their profile with the Company:
   https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1588/
3. If that fails, contact LinkedIn with the name of the company you would like to edit:
   https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1591/~/editing-a-company-page